# On success of ajax post, how to send a POST request with JQuery .load() method

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, web-development-server

After a successful Ajax post, I would like the template associated with POST in the handler to be rendered with JQuery's .load() method.  The GET request keeps getting called after a successful POST ...so the template associated with GET is getting rendered instead of the one associate with POST.  Thanks for any hints you can give.

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {  
    $(".topic_submit").click(function() {  
    var topic = $("#topic").val();
    refresh = 'false'
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/mentorlist",  
            data: {'topic': topic},  
            success: function(dataString) {  
                $('#mentor_list').load('/mentorlist');
                console.log('**mentor_list div updated via ajax.**'); 
            }  
        });  
        return true;  
    });  
});
```

**HTML Form:**

```
<form id="topic_search_form"  name="topic_search_form" action="">
 Topic:  <input id ="topic" type="text" name="topic" size="60" placeholder="Search by Keyword" />
<input type="submit" class="topic_submit" name="topic_submit" value="Search" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `.load()` in that fashion without additional data you are really just calling a simplified version of `.get()`. If you're trying to use the data returned from the post, you should be doing

```
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "/mentorlist",  
        data: {'topic': topic},  
        success: function(dataString) {  
            $('#mentor_list').html(dataString);
            console.log('**mentor_list div updated via ajax.**'); 
        }  
    });
```

Comment: That's not true. `load()` can still initiate a `POST` request. see http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I specifically said `When you call .load() in that fashion without additional data`. Yes, you can do post if you provided additional arguments.

Comment: @haim770 No need for sorry bud. I'm impressed that you realized that you had an extra `});` by yourself in your original response. Good job :)

Comment: Thank you @kpsuperplane! That worked like a charm-  I am still learning this, but can you tell me how ."html(dataString)" worked instead of the .load()?  -Thanks

Comment: @MattEllis, remember how it has `success: function(dataString)`? What that does is it puts the response from that post request in that variable. So all you have to do is change the innerhtml (with `.html()`) to the response from the server. Basically that `success` function is called after a successful post request and it puts the response in that variable :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two subsequent requests to load the response data into your `#mentor_list`, you can simply call `load()` once and make is use `POST` as follows:

```
$(".topic_submit").click(function()
{
    var topic = $("#topic").val();
    refresh = 'false';

    $('#mentor_list').load('/mentorlist', { topic: topic });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) does allow a POST, but you have to give it a data object... try giving it a new object...

```
$('#mentor_list').load('/mentorlist', {});
```